# Python v3 Find The Longest Word (Error Message)

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.4 and am getting an error message " 'wordlist is not defined' " in my program. What am I doing wrong? Please respond with code.

The program is to find the longest word:

```
def find_longest_word(a):
    length = len(a[0])
    word = a[0]
for i in wordlist:
    word = (i)
    length = len(i)
return word, length

def main():
    wordlist = input("Enter a list of words seperated by spaces ".split()
    word, length = find_longestest_word(wordlist)
    print (word, "is",length,"characters long.")

main()
```

Comment: Your question's title isn't very informative...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the problems with your code indentation, your `find_longest_word()` function doesn't really have any logic in it to find the longest word. Also, you pass it a parameter named `a`, but you never use `a` in the function, instead you use `wordlist`...

The code below does what you want. The `len()` function in Python is very efficient because all Python container objects store their current length, so it's rarely worth bothering to store length in a separate variable. So my `find_longest_word()` simply stores the longest word it's encountered so far.

```
def find_longest_word(wordlist):
    longest = ''
    for word in wordlist:
        if len(word) > len(longest):
            longest = word
    return longest

def main():
    wordlist = input("Enter a list of words separated by spaces: ").split()
    word = find_longest_word(wordlist)
    print(word, "is" ,len(word), "characters long.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost exactly what I need! My only problem now is that my output is only taking the first word, and giving me the number of characters it is. I need to be able to enter several words (for instance: cat dog mouse bird pig) and have it say, "mouse is the longest word."

Comment: @NewAtThis: That's odd. Is it printing any error messages? Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? I'm using Python 2, so I'm using `raw_input` instead of `input`, like this: `wordlist = raw_input("Enter a list of words separated by spaces: ").split()`. But my code above should work properly on Python 3.

Comment: Version 3. It does work correctly, and is doing exactly what the code says without issue. I'm just wondering how to change the code to have it tell me what the longest word is, instead of telling me how many characters the longest word is. For example, right now if I answer "dog" it will respond, "dog 3" but I want to be able to say "dog cat mouse" and have it respond, "mouse is the longest word."

Comment: @NewAtThis: If you type `cat dog mouse bird pig` at the prompt does it print `mouse is 5 characters long.` ?

Comment: @NewAtThis: Ok. In that case, you can just change the `print()` call to `print(word, "is the longest word.")`. PS. If you like my answer, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

The line "return word, length" is outside any function. The closest function is "find_longest_word(a)", so if you want it to be a part of that function, you need to indent lines 4-7.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Definitely a duh moment. Perhaps you can help me futher? Now I'm getting this error message:

Comment: "NameError: name 'wordlist' is not defined." How do i define it?

Comment: On line 4 you use the variable wordlist in your for loop but wordlist is defined in your main() function.

Comment: It looks like you may want to replace 'wordlist' on line 4 with 'a' since that's the variable name you use after being passed to 'find_longest_word()'

Comment: As a side note, the python interpreter should be spitting out line numbers for where these errors occur. Sometimes they're a bit cryptic, but in this case it should have given you the exact line where you used the undefined variable. Try to trace through your program flow so you can utilize all that junk the interpreter spits out when it explodes on you.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation matters in Python. As the error says, you have the return outside the function. Try:

```
def find_longest_word(a):
    length = len(a[0])
    word = a[0]
    for i in wordlist:
        word = (i)
        length = len(i)
    return word, length

def main():
    wordlist = input("Enter a list of words seperated by spaces ".split()
word, length = find_longestest_word(wordlist)
print (word, "is",length,"characters long.")

main()
```

Comment: This will still fail with a `NameError`; OP needs to indent the second-to-last and third-to-last lines as well so they're inside `main` (and spell the name of the function right, for that matter).

Comment: Yes, I am getting a NameError, but even after I indented the 3rd to last line. It's saying the name 'word' is not defined. I'm not sure where in the code to do this?

Comment: @NewAtThis You need to indent both the `word, length` line and the `print` line for this to work. Otherwise, Python doesn't know what to do with the `print` function.

Comment: Thanks, this got me to a point where it asked the user for input. Now I'm getting this message: "NameError: name 'wordlist' is not defined". I know I need to define it, I'm just not sure where/how.

Answer (score 0):

In python the indentation is very important. It should be:

```
def find_longest_word(a):
    length = len(a[0])
    word = a[0]
    for i in wordlist:
        word = (i)
        length = len(i)
    return word, length
```

But because of the function name, I think the implementation is wrong.